# Let $K$ be compact with $K \subset \mathbb D$. Also let $a \in K$ and $u$ be a positive harmonic function on $\mathbb D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $K$ be compact with $K \subset \mathbb D$. Also let $a \in K$ and $u$ be a positive harmonic function on $\mathbb D$. Prove there exists a constant $C = C(a, K) > 0$ such that for all $z \in K$ 
>   $$
> \frac{u(a)}{C} \le u(z) \le Cu(a).
> $$
>   **Edit:** The constant $C$ should depend on $a$ and $K$ only, not $u$.

I think Harnack's inequality should be used.

Since $K$ is compact inside an open set there exists $\delta = d(K, \partial \mathbb D) > 0$. Then we can take a disc centered at $a$ of radius $1 - \delta < R < 1$. So Harnack's inequality can be applied on $\overline{D(a, R)}$ however we don't know if this disc covers all of $K$. I'm stuck here.

I've noted that we can take $K \setminus D(a, R)$ which is a compact set, thus we can take the open cover
$$
O = \{ B(z, R) : z \in K \setminus D(a, R) \}
$$
and obtain a finite subcover $O_N = \{ B(z_i, R) : 1 \le i \le N \}$. Not sure if this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this for compact subsets of any connected open set by an argument like what you started. For the disk you can cheat and give a simpler argument, using the fact that $u$ is the Poisson integral of  some positive measure on the circle. (Which of course is how Harnack's inequality is proved in the first place -- look back at that proof and you see it actually gives a proof of this.)

To be explicit: There exists a positive measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb T$ such that $$u(z)=\int_{\Bbb T}P_z(t)\,d\mu(t),$$where $P_z(t)$ is the Poisson kernel. Given $K$ compact, you can show that there exist $c>0$ and $C>0$ such that $$c\le P_z(t)\le C\quad(z\in K, t\in\Bbb T).$$Hint for that: there exists $r<1$ so $|z|\le r$ for every $z\in K$. This shows that $$c u(0)\le u(z)\le C u(0)\quad(z\in K),$$so that if $a\in K$ then $$u(z)\le  C u(0)\le \frac Cc u(a),\quad(z\in K)$$and similarly $u(z)\ge\frac cC u(a)$.

**If you don't know that fact about positive harmonic functions and measures:** for $0<r<1$ define $u_r(z)=u(rz)$. It's enough to prove the inequality with $u_r$ in place of $u$, since $u_r\to u$ pointwise as $r\to1$. But $u_r$ is continuous on the closed disk, so you can apply the Poisson fomrmula for $u_r$ as above.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm not exactly sure what you mean (I'm probably not understanding what you really mean). I think you are suggesting that I show Harnack's inequality centered at $a$ of an appropriate radius $R$ can be used to obtain the desired inequality. But it seems to me I cannot be guaranteed of such an $R$ covering the set $K$.

Comment: @user330531 No, that's not what I'm suggesting. When I said you could  use the fact that $u$ is the Poisson integral of a positive measure I was suggesting that you could use the fact that $u$ is the Poisson integral of a positive measure.

Comment: Sorry, I should have really asked what does $u$ is the Poisson integral of a positive measure mean.

Comment: @user330531 Do you know the proof of Harnack's inequality?

Comment: Yes, in the proof we use the Poisson integral formula and the triangle inequality essentially to find bounds for $u(z)$ for $z$ in our disc $D(P, r)$, and we finally use mean value property to evaluate the integral $u(P + Re^{i\theta})$ as $u(P)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $K$ is compact und $u$ is continuous on $K$, there are $c,d \in K$ such that

$u(c) \le u(z) \le u(d)$ for all $z \in K$.

For $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $\frac{u(a)}{n} \to 0$ and $nu(a) \to + \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Hence there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$\frac{u(a)}{N} \le u(c)$ and $u(d) \le Nu(a)$.

Now take $C(a,K)=N$.

Comment: the main point of this problem is that C is supposed to depend only on a and K and not on u. The same constant should work for all positive harmonic function and that is where Harnack's inequality comes into the picture. Surely, the wording of the OP could have been better.

Comment: This answers the question the OP asked, but not the question he meant to/should have asked. It's unfortunately common in analysis that the "there exists C such that" appears much later in the sentence than it should to  make the actual intended order of the quantifiers clear.

Comment: I should have been far more explicit about what $C$ depends on. I think this idea if helpful, I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.